# Drawing rectangle/lines using PatBlt

Tags: mfc

I am drawing ruler using the sample application given in the link.

http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Source_Code/MFC-MDI-SDI-Example-create-ruler-scrollview-splitter.htm

On moving cursor they are drawing black line marker. I want to draw red color line like in microsoft paint application.

In the sample they are using below code for drawing line.

What needs to be done to draw red color line.

```
void CRulerView::DrawCursorPos(CPoint NewPos)
 {
    if (((m_rulerType == RT_HORIZONTAL) && (NewPos.x > m_DocSize.cx*m_fZoomFactor)) ||
    ((m_rulerType == RT_VERTICAL) && ((NewPos.y) > m_DocSize.cy*m_fZoomFactor)))
    return;

CDC* pDC = GetDC();
// set the map mode right
int oldMapMode = pDC->SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);
//HBRUSH hBr=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
//pDC->SelectObject(hBr);
//CBrush* pTempBrush = NULL;
    // pTempBrush = (CBrush*)pDC->SelectObject(&hBr);

CRect clientRect;
GetClientRect(&clientRect);
if (m_rulerType==RT_HORIZONTAL)
{

    // erase the previous position
    pDC->PatBlt(m_lastPos.x, clientRect.top, 1, clientRect.bottom, DSTINVERT);
    // draw the new position
    m_lastPos.x = NewPos.x;
    pDC->PatBlt(m_lastPos.x, clientRect.top, 1, clientRect.bottom, DSTINVERT);
}
else // (m_rulerType==RT_VERTICAL)
{
    // erase the previous position
    pDC->PatBlt(clientRect.left, m_lastPos.y, clientRect.right, 1, DSTINVERT);
    // draw the new position
    m_lastPos.y = NewPos.y;
    pDC->PatBlt(clientRect.left, m_lastPos.y, clientRect.right, 1, DSTINVERT);
}
//pDC->SelectObject(&pTempBrush);

pDC->SetMapMode(oldMapMode);
ReleaseDC(pDC);
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you uncomment the lines that selects the red color brush?

Comment: when I uncomment the lines that selects the red color brush, getting black color line only not the red color line

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with what you pass as the 5th parameter to [PatBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162778(v=vs.85))?

Comment: If I try with PATCOPY as 5th parameter, I am getting red color line but previous line is not getting erased.